# How to Add context menu entries for Windows 10 start menu tiles?

Tags: contextmenu, windows-10, startmenu

It is possible to add custom context menu items and submenus throughout Windows Explorer via registry entries and dlls. However, this does not add those items to the Start Menu/Screen in Windows 8/8.1/10 etc.

Is there a different way to add extensions to the context menu in the Start Menu or is it hard-coded with just the default context menu items (pin, unpin, resize, uninstall, etc.)?

Comment: Have you found the answer?